# Compiling Java LWJGL project with NetBeans (package org.lwjgl does not exist)

Tags: java, netbeans, lwjgl

I try to compile a ([LWJGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Java_Game_Library)) Java project using [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans).
I clicked on the project -> properties and under Libraries -> Compile. I added the Jars location, the source files location and javadoc location.

Still when I try to build the project I get the error:

> package org.lwjgl does not exist.

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove all libraries, "build and clean" (obviously compile give 100% errors...). Try to add all libraries, press "ok". After that wait for "scanning the projects" to finish successfully and after that retry to "build and clean".

Answer (score 0):

I added the directory location of the jar files and I needed to add each jar individually.